# Issue with Makefile - section executed twice

Tags: c++, c, makefile, d

I may not be a Makefile-guru, but I have some experience with them in the past. However, I've got a (rather unimportant) issue, which still baffles me.

**Here's my Makefile :**

```
#-------------------------
# Definitions
#-------------------------

APP   = lgm

# Tools & commands

CC    = gcc
LEX   = lex
YACC  = /usr/local/bin/bison
RM    = rm
CP    = cp
MV    = mv
DMD   = dmd

# Paths

SRC     = src
BIN     = bin
TEST    = test
LIB     = lib

# C stuff

CC_HEADERS  = logramm.tab.h
CC_SOURCES  = lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
CC_OBJECTS  = lex.yy.o logramm.tab.o

CC_LEXER    = logramm.l
CC_PARSER   = logramm.y

# D stuff

D_SOURCES   = main.d
D_OBJECTS   = main.o

D_LFLAGS    = -m64

#-------------------------
# Main Functions
#-------------------------

all: ${APP} clean

${APP}: ${CC_OBJECTS} ${D_OBJECTS}
    ${DMD} ${CC_OBJECTS} ${D_OBJECTS} -of${APP} ${D_FLAGS}
    ${MV} ${APP} ${BIN}

${D_OBJECTS}:
    ${DMD} -c ${D_SOURCES}

${CC_OBJECTS}: ${CC_SOURCES}
    ${CC} -g -c ${CC_SOURCES}

${CC_SOURCES}: setup
    ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
    ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}

setup:
    ${CP} ${SRC}/*.d .
    ${CP} ${SRC}/*.l .
    ${CP} ${SRC}/*.y .

clean:
    ${RM} *.d *.y *.l *.o *.hh *.c *.h
```

**The trouble is :**

When I'm looking at the output of `make all`, the `${CC_SOURCES}` part is executed twice (2 `lex`, 2 `bison` commands). E.g. It outputs :

```
cp src/*.d .
cp src/*.l .
cp src/*.y .
lex logramm.l
/usr/local/bin/bison -d logramm.y
lex logramm.l
/usr/local/bin/bison -d logramm.y
gcc -g -c lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
dmd -c main.d
dmd lex.yy.o logramm.tab.o main.o -oflgm 
mv lgm bin
rm *.d *.y *.l *.o *.hh *.c *.h
rm: *.hh: No such file or directory
make: *** [clean] Error 1
```

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE :**

I've just managed to fix it, by taking `setup` from `${CC_SOURCES}` and putting it at the `all` section, like :

```
all: setup ${APP} clean
```

So, it's ok. However, I still don't understand *why*. Have I misinterpreted the way Makefiles are structured? Any input would be more than welcome! :-)

Comment: `Setup` isn't a file. I.e., for each of `${CC_SOURCES}` components (`lex.yy.c` and `logramm.tab.c`) exist no up-to-date prequisite. Thus, the rule is executed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a basic misunderstanding of how make interprets rules with multiple targets: this makefile is really not going to work.  Let's expand the rule that runs the lex/yacc:

```
lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c: setup
        ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
        ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}
```

Make interprets this as if it were this (in an explicit rule, multiple targets create a separate rule for each target):

```
lex.yy.c: setup
        ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
        ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}

logramm.tab.c: setup
        ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
        ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}
```

Now you can probably see your issue.  Make wants to build lex.yy.o and that depends on lex.yy.c, so make tries to build that.  It sees that it depends on `setup`, which doesn't exist (because nothing creates it, but if someone WERE to create that file in your directory it would break badly).  So, it run the lex and yacc steps (both, since that's the recipe) to build `lex.yy.c`.

Then it goes through exactly the same thing to build `logramm.tab.c`... thus the rules are run twice.

You have an identical problem with your object files; expanding that rule we see:

```
lex.yy.o logramm.tab.o: lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
        ${CC} -g -c lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
```

which is identical to:

```
lex.yy.o: lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
        ${CC} -g -c lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c

logramm.tab.o: lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
        ${CC} -g -c lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c
```

which is clearly not right.

Also, your `setup` rule (since it never exists) will cause everything to rebuild every time.

Your solution is better WRT setup, since the source files don't depend on it so they won't always be rebuilt.  You still have the broken rules for object files.  Also your solution will not work if you ever wanted to enable parallel builds, because the setup may be run in parallel with the other targets: you really WANT the dependency to ensure ordering.

In general when writing makefiles you should (a) have one rule to build one target, and (b) ensure the rule builds EXACTLY the target you told make it would build.

Try using this instead:

```
all: ${BIN}/${APP} clean

${BIN}/${APP}: ${APP}
        ${CP} $< $@

${APP}: ${CC_OBJECTS} ${D_OBJECTS}
    ${DMD} $^ -of$@ ${D_FLAGS}

%.o : %.d
        ${DMD} -c $<

%.o: %.c
        ${CC} -g -c $<

%: ${SRC}/%
        ${CP} $< $@

lex.yy.c: ${CC_LEXER}
        ${LEX} $<

%.tab.c %.tab.h: %.y
        ${YACC} -d $<

clean:
        ${RM} *.d *.y *.l *.o *.hh *.c *.h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really informative! I'm really having trouble deciding which one of these 2 great answers to accept; but for reasons of being fair (@Jonathan's answer was earlier by 1 minutes) I'll go with his answer. However, I still appreciate it! :-)

Comment: That's fine... just to note, though, that there are other issues with your makefile that you need to address, in addition to the ones Jonathan noted.

Comment: I'm currently looking into it. Seems like I have to do a lot of catching up with Makefiles too. Used them in the past quite lots of times, but more-or-less along the same lines. And since it kept working, I didn't bother reading up more on the subject... My bad! :-)

Comment: The makefile you have will "work" (as long as you don't try using parallel builds), but it will run rebuilds of targets that don't need to be rebuilt.  Here's a short test: if you run `make`, then immediately run `make` again without changing anything, and make actually rebuilds something, then likely your makefile has a problem.  Also if you modify one file and run `make` and unrelated files are rebuilt, your makefile has a problem.

Comment: OK, so I tried *parts* of your suggestion and they seem to be working fine. However, when I copied all of it, there are errors : `make: *** No rule to make target 'lex.yy.o', needed by 'lgm'.  Stop.` Any ideas?

Comment: And another one - (I think I've fixed the above one, by re-introducing my rule for `${CC_SOURCES}` - they do not exist, they are created by lex/bison). Now the files don't seem to be copied at the present directory at all. Pff...

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the bison/flex :-p hang on  Ok try that

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: you've chosen to accept the answer I think you should accept. MadScientist has gone above and beyond the call of duty, where I only made a barely sufficient answer.  Always accept the most helpful answer.  Only if two answers are so similar that there is nothing to choose between them in content should time be the deciding factor.  That seldom happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, I decided to change my mind; just because it didn't feel right. Anyway, SO should have at times the option of awarding 2 answers at the same time. This would be the fairest of all. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that `CC_SOURCES = lex.yy.c logramm.tab.c` so the target line (plus actions):

```
${CC_SOURCES}: setup
    ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
    ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}
```

is equivalent to:

```
lex.yy.c: setup
    ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
    ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}

logramm.tab.c: setup
    ${LEX} ${CC_LEXER}
    ${YACC} -d ${CC_PARSER}
```

The `setup` rule has no dependencies, but isn't a (GNU `make` extension) `.PHONY` target either (and I'm not sure that being a phony target would help, either), so it doesn't exist.  Therefore, when `make` is trying to ensure that `lex.yy.c` is up to date, it has to execute the rules for `setup`; ditto for `logramm.tab.c`; hence the double execution.

Your solution looks reasonable.  You could explore `.PHONY` and see whether that helps if you're using GNU `make` and don't mind being tied to GNU `make`.

Answer (score 1):

This comes down to the way `make` handles dependencies. You can always examine exactly what `make` is doing by passing the `-d` flag (at least for GNU Make, ymmv, also consider adding `-r` if you aren't using any built-in rules as they clutter the output substantially).

Here's what happens in the case where `setup` is a dependency of `${CC_SOURCES}`

```
...
Does lex.yy.c exist? no, okay check its prerequisites
    Does setup exist? no, okay check its prerequisites
        No prerequisites, run the recipe
    Prerequisites for lex.yy.c done, run the recipe
Does logramm.tab.c exist? yes, but check its prerequisites
    We already built setup, so prune this prerequisite, but treat it as newer than logramm.tab.c
    Prerequisites for logramm.tab.c done, run the recipe
...
```

Here's what happens in the case where `setup` is a dependency of `all`

```
...
Does setup exist? no, okay check its prerequisites
    No prerequisites, run the recipe
...
Does lex.yy.c exist? no, okay check its prerequisites
    No prerequisites, run the recipe
Does logramm.tab.c exist? yes, but check its prerequisites
    No prerequisites, so done
...
```